# Image indexing in multimodal model

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to create a probability prediction model using numerical values (embeddings), text and now images. My problem is that while there are 10k images, they get referenced at different times in different samples. So as an example:

Sample 1 has:

- Winner ID: 120
- Loser ID: 27
- Winner Name: ABC
- Loser Name: DEF
- Winner Img: 120.png
- Loser Img: 27.png

but then we have Sample 129:

- Winner ID: 22
- Loser ID: 120
- Winner Name: XYZ
- Loser Name: ABC
- Winner Img: 22.png
- Loser Img: 120.png

There are about 100k of these samples so adding redundant images is going to be costly and the images themselves don't have labels to them, they are just part of a series of features.

I was wondering if there was any way to index an image in Tensorflow/Keras/Python in general to accomplish this without having to copy the image for each input sample. Sort of like word embeddings (but not learned) and for pictures.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at tf.lookup.StaticHashTable. Not sure how it works with Keras' `model.fit` function but I will add more/answer this with what I find

Comment: Upon further inspection, with my code and some empirical results I am not actually going to continue looking into this (extra information doesn't help at all in this case). If it is answered anyway then I will definitely accept it. I think StaticHashTable inside of a subclassed keras.layers.Layer would do the trick. Unless I am mistaken about how datasets work in TF/Keras then this should be a built in feature in my opinion (I hope I am mistaken though)